# (django) getting the primary key form a submitting form and use it for redirection

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django model called "post" and I want that when adding a post with the url:

```
    url(r'^newpost/', views.PostFormView.as_view(), name='add'),
```

it redirects me to the detail page of the added post with the url:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PostDetailView, name='detail'),
```

where pk is the id (primary key of the added post)

My post model is as following:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  speciality = models.ForeignKey(Speciality, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  level = models.ManyToManyField(Level)

  date_post = models.DateTimeField()
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  date_delete = models.DateTimeField()
```

My PostFormView view to add a new post is:

```
class PostFormView(View):
  form_class = PostCreationForm
  template_name = 'posts/new_post.html'

  def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

  def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.person_id=request.user.id
        post.save()

        if post is not None:
            return redirect('posts:detail', post.id)
```

and my submitting form is as follow:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'posts:detail' pk=1 %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% include 'form-template.html' %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Add the post </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

if i put an empty action "" or I change the url to another view or I remove the pk in the form I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /posts/newpost/
table posts_post has no column named person_id
```

How can I submit the form, get the id of the submitted post and redirect it to the detail url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with submitting or redirecting.

You've added the `person` field to your model, but you haven't run the database migrations.

Comment: It's true, I forgot to migrate the database. Now it works